# Arduino Programming IR Sensors and Actuators

Tags: electrical-engineering, robotics, computer-engineering

Create the circuit below (Arduino)

[image]

You are supposed to use the following code (must download correct library if IDE is too old):

```
#include <IRemote.h>
int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}
void loop()
{
 if (irrecv.decode(&results))
MECH 303
Page 5 of 6
 {
 Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
 irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
 }
}
```

Now, I am trying to figure how to make different keys. I should be able to
transmit the code received by the IR
remote in your starter kit. I want to write down at least the codes for at least four keys. I need to be able to write the
keys of: forward, backword, 0, and 1.

I am pretty stuck and need help making these keys for all 4 movements

Thank you
Lauren Quinones

Comment: I think this should be moved to StackOverflow. It's all about programming.

Comment: Can you please share some details of the IR remote? What is the IR remote control protocol you are using? Example RC5, RC6, Sanyo, Panasonic etc